# reading strings from file to struct array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I am trying to read strings from file and add them to my array of structs but when i do i get some random characters at the end of one or two strings.Here is my code for reading strings line by line:

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
strncpy(&structures[i].id,line,4);   //copies the first four characters to my array of structures
...
}
```

When i print out the structures[0].id it prints "WW23�" when it should be just "WW23".It does that with couple of strings, although not with all of them.
My struct looks like this.

```
struct observers
{
 char id[13];
 ...
};
```

It reads from file properly at least it gets the integer values right.

Comment: Post the definition of `id`.  Is it `char id[4]`?  If so ` structures[i].id[4] = '\0'` is bad.

Answer (score 4):

You are not terminating the string. Add '\0' at the end `structures[i].id[4] = '\0'`. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add '\0' as the 5'th character to terminate the string.